# Modern tools deterministic communication applications

Tags: big-picture, communication-complexity, survey

Partition number, Fooling-set method along with rank method provide important tools to identify deterministic communication complexity of a function. These techniques were identified some decades before. What other modern techniques have been invented to identify deterministic complexity of a function? Which functions have these been utilized to solve?

Could tools from information theory, pattern matrix be useful in saying anything about deterministic complexity both in single user, multi user situations?